# 301 redirect is not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, web-config

I've had a problem with 301 redirect. We've got a site (https://domain) and wanted to set preferred domain (non-www), for this - i verify 2 versions (https domain and https www.domain) with google analytics and html page. 
And when i choose a preferred domain - it gives me This Error: Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that you own http www.domain/. Please verify http www.domain/.

Ok. I delete my https www.domain/ - version, and verify  http www.domain/ - version (without "s")... And it works! BUT! 
My seo tools(seositecheckup, woorank...) - said, that i didnt have 301 redirect yet.. 
How it is possible? 
When I'm verifying http version - it works, but tools are not seeing theese changes. 
When I'm verifying all 4 versions (2(http and https) with www and 2 without www) - it works, but tools are not seeing theese changes too. 
When I'm verifying https version - search consule didnt allow me to set my preferred domain, by giving me This Error: Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that you own http www.domain. Please verify http www.domain

Here is my code on web config:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain$" />
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://domain/{R:0}"
redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com" ignoreCase="false" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

Try this code